# Picasson resize before save to cache

Tags: android, picasso

I get large image from Api like 3000px x 4000px but i dont have to save them at this size in cache(i would never display image that size, and that get me performance issue).

How to resize image before Picasso save in in cache, before display or when i even does not want to display image(preload)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `RequestCreator.resize(int targetWidth, int targetHeight)` method.

For example:

`picasso.load(imageUri).resize(240, 240).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);`

Comment: but what if i want use `fetch()` instead of `info()`? and i when i want to keep image ratio?

Comment: I believe `resize()` provides target dimensions, so as long as you don't use an image scale type that stretches to fit, Picasso keeps the correct aspect ratio. Looking at the docs, it looks like `fetch()` does everything `into()` does:   "Asynchronously fulfills the request without a ImageView or Target, and invokes the target Callback with the result. This is useful when you want to warm up the cache with an image."